# Debug code to change printer and view on Workbook Open

Tags: excel, vba

Can you see what is wrong with this code?  It likes to hang up on the SendKeys lines.  Using Wait seemed to solve the problem, but it now sometimes hangs up on the Wait lines.  If I use choose Continue from the "Code Execution Interrupted" pop-up, it continues and does the job. The purpose of this code is to have the user open this file after using a label printer and have this file automatically change the printer and reset the view to what they need.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
    bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Sheet3.Calculate
    Application.ActivePrinter = Sheet3.Range("B27").Value
    Application.SendKeys "{Escape}", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
    Application.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageLayoutView
        
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the `On Error Resume Next` line?

Comment: It fails on the first Wait line if I remove the On Error Resume Next.  Also, I had to delete and replace the file that I applied the "magic" fix to because it then started causing the Excel title line to flash and things be weird.  I can continue to tell users to click on "Continue" whenever the error box pops up because that works and only happens sometimes.  This all started with me trying to solve the Debug issue, which was on SendKeys.lines.

Comment: The error most likely occurs because of an invalid printer assignment in the `ActivePrinter` line as the others are pretty standard.  Using `On Error Resume Next` only hides the errors, it doesn't eliminate them.  You may want to look at the printer assignment in `B27` when it is failing and figure out why.  This may help...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activeprinter

Comment: THANK YOU, DARRELL!  Found that this file only executes without the error if the printer listed in B27 is on -- or this was not the first Excel file opened after computer shut down.  Yes, I did shut down many times and open many files to prove this, haha.  I have other files that use the same coding with no problem, Anyway, this never happens to users because those printers are on when they use the file and they also open another file before using this file.